# Creating and appending csv files

Tags: python, xml, append, cvs, chron

I am working on my first python project and am in over my head.
I am trying to collect bike share data from an xml feed.

I want to capture this data every n minutes, lets say 5 for now, then create a csv file of that data.
Additionally I want to create a second file that appends the first file so I have a historical database.
The headers in the csv are:
[ "id", "name", "terminalName", "lastCommWithServer", "lat", "long", "installed", "locked", "installDate", "removalDate", "temporary", "public", "nbBikes", "nbEmptyDocks", "latestUpdateTime" ]
I made a start but I'm not going no where slowly! Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have but the csv writing is a mess.

```
import urllib
import csv

url = 'http://www.capitalbikeshare.com/data/stations/bikeStations.xml'
connection = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = connection.read()

with open('statuslog.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(data)
```

Comment: you can open a file with "ab" (and variants), the "a" will let you append to the file.

Comment: What are the results you're getting now?

Comment: You're opening an `XML` feed and dumping it into your `.csv` file. You probably wanna parse the XML first, extract what you want. Put it in a `list` and **then** write that `list` to your `.csv`

Comment: You need to parse your data. For parsing I would recommend using BeautifulSoup, which is an easy to use package. The data extracted, save it in a list of lists. For each list corresponding to an entry, just use join to make the csv row for that item, depending on the separator that you need. Each of those new lines created with join, append them to your CSV file. Finally, append that csv to your log file.

Comment: @chris - used 'ab' and it worked!

Comment: @BorrajaX - I parsed it first and  it was much cleaner!

Comment: @SalvadorMedina - I actually used elementtree, but thanks for pointing me towards using a parsing package.